# Adding title / `data` attributes to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on page. How can I add a title and `data` attributes to this button or div using js / jquery?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">TEST</button>
```

expected output:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="category" data-placement="middle" title="Home">TEST</button>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: use `.attr()` method

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('button').attr('data-toggle','category').attr('data-placement','middle').attr('title','Home')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">TEST</button>
```

Use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Description: Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

To set attr

`.attr('attrname','attrvalue')`

To get attr value

`.attr('attrname')`

Comment: Looks good. The button already exist on page. I only need to add the title and data attributes.

Comment: like that you need to set the `.attr()` to set attr you do like `.attr('attrname','attrvalue')` to get attr value you do `.attr('attrname')` @Becky

Comment: LIke this? `$('.btn-secondary').attr('data-toggle','category')`